# How to output a 'parent field' value in a Playa Tag Pair?

Tags: playa

I'm really struggling to output a parent field value within a Playa tag pair. I've had to resort to using php in my template to do this. Is there a way I can do this without using php in my template? Thanks.

I had to enable php and do this:

```
<?php $parent_field = {parent_field} ?>
{playa_field}
    <a href="{url_title}">{title} <?php echo $parent_field ?></a>
{/playa_field}
```

As this doesn't output the {parent_field} content within the tag pair:

```
{playa_field}
    <a href="{url_title}">{title} {parent_field}</a>
{/playa_field}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just need to use the [playa:parents](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html) tag pair instead of the fieldtype tag pair?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up prefixing the Playa fields. The following code allows you to access parent field/s.

```
{playa_field var_prefix="pl"}
    <a href="{pl:url_title}">{pl:title} {parent_field}</a>
{/playa_field}
```